# cannot invoke an expression in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, object, primeng

i would create a dynamic menu. For that I use primeng [menu panel](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/panelmenu)

I declare my item variable

```
 items: MenuItem[]=[];
```

I have two JS object to integrate to the menu, groupsItem and 
ejsItem

Here's their format:

```
groupsItem  = {

    code:"",
    name:""

}

ejsItem  = {

    code:"",
    name:"",
    codeBusinessGroup:"",
    nameBusinessGroup

}
```

I would that for every groupsItem.code I check if `groupsItem.code==ejsItem.codebusinessGroup` in ejsItem list. If yes I add ejsItem.name as a sub menu to groupsItem.name.

For example:

```
groupsItem  = {
    code:"123",
    name:"Facebook"    
}

ejsItem  = {   
    code:"222",
    name:"Whatapp",
    codeBusinessGroup:"123",
    nameBusinessGroup:"Facebook"    
}
```

The menu will be :

- Facebook

  -Whatsapp

I have coded a function to create the menu that I have OnInit

```
createMenu() {
    let groupsItem: any[]=[];
    groupsItem=this.getCacheResults("group");
    let ejsItem: any[];
    ejsItem=this.getCacheResults("ej");
    for(let i=0;i<groupsItem.length;i++) {
        this.items.push({label:groupsItem[i].name});
        console.log("Item",this.items[i])
        for(let j =0;j<ejsItem.length;j++) {
            if(ejsItem[j].codeBusinessGroup==groupsItem[i].code)
                this.items[i].items.push({label:ejsItem[j].name}) // items to add them as sub-menu
        }
    }
}
```

I got this error :

```
 ERROR in src/app/shared/left-menu/left-menu.component.ts(115,5): error TS2349: Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type '((...items:MenuItem[]) => number) | ((...items: MenuItem[][]) => number)' has no compatible call signatures.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `items` property of `MenuItem` is defined as `MenuItem[] | MenuItem[][]` (meaning it can either be an array of `MenuItem` or an array of arrays of `MenuItem`) so yo can't call `push` on a property with such a type, because it is not clear to the compiler if you are trying to push into a `MenuItem[]`or a `MenuItem[][]`

The simplest solution is to create the array of type `MenuItem[]` and then assign it directly

```
let childItems: MenuItem[] = [];
for (let j = 0; j < ejsItem.length; j++) {
    if (ejsItem[j].codeBusinessGroup == groupsItem[i].code) {
        childItems.push({ label: ejsItem[j].name }) // items to add them as sub-menu
    }
}
this.items[i].items = childItems;
```